# How can I use Docker with socks5 in Ubuntu?

Tags: systemd, proxy, docker

I have been trying to run docker through a local socks5 proxy, I have tried setting the environment variable as such:

```bsh
export ALL_PROXY=127.0.0.1:1080
```

But it made no difference as if Docker wasn't reading it, I also tried putting the config in `~/.docker/config.json`:

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"
   }
 }
}
```

But this doesn't work either. What's the problem and how can I run Docker with a socks5 proxy on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `docker.service` in Ubuntu is agnostic to user's environment variables, but if it were to be passed to the `docker.service` itself, then it works.

I got it working by adding the following line to the `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` file, right before `ExecStart`:

```bash
Environment="ALL_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"
```

So my `docker.service` file looked like this:

```bash
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
BindsTo=containerd.service
After=network-online.target firewalld.service containerd.service
Wants=network-online.target
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
Environment="ALL_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always

# Note that StartLimit* options were moved from "Service" to "Unit" in systemd 229.
# Both the old, and new location are accepted by systemd 229 and up, so using the old location
# to make them work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitBurst=3

# Note that StartLimitInterval was renamed to StartLimitIntervalSec in systemd 230.
# Both the old, and new name are accepted by systemd 230 and up, so using the old name to make
# this option work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitInterval=60s

# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity

# Comment TasksMax if your systemd version does not support it.
# Only systemd 226 and above support this option.
TasksMax=infinity

# set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers
Delegate=yes

# kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This seems to have fixed the problem for me and it is working on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use the `privoxy` and forward it to your socks5 proxy so you can use privoxy as a https/http proxy.